# Accessing a value from a key in a ruby hash

Tags: ruby, hash

So I have a hash:

```
test =  {"_id"=>"5516c07ba520e0066c9ac53c", "accounts"=>[], "address"=>{"zip"=>"45245", "state"=>" Ohio", "city"=>"Cincinnati", "street"=>"3320 Wagner Road"}, "first_name"=>"Black", "last_name"=>"Bart"}
```

and I'm just playing around in the ruby console. To access the value at _id, I thought the command should just be test.[key] . But I run test.[_id] and I keep getting errors. This seems pretty simple, but I'm missing some syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there's no `.`. Otherwise, you would have to access arrays like `arr.[](0)`, add numbers like `1.+(2)`, etc. To make this more "natural," Ruby adds syntaxic sugar that removes the need for the `.` when calling methods with certain names (such as `[]`, `+`, etc.).

Secondly, you don't have a variable called `_id`. You need to pass it as a string.

```
puts test["_id"]
```

Comment: The is at least one exception to that rule that I know of (there may be others), namely, one of the four ways to invoke `call` on a lambda `l`: `l.(*args)`, where the dot between `l` and `(` is required. (The other three ways are `l.call(*args)`, `l.yield(*args)` and `last[*args]`.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `test["_id"]` instead